# Warning on using strtotime in php?

Tags: php, strtotime

Warning: mysql_result() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given on this line

```
$time   = mysql_result( date('d F Y', strtotime($i["time_stamp"])));
```

Comment: what exactly you are doing.

Comment: doesn't look making sense. `mysql_result` with `date` ?!

Comment: my timestamp showing **1357294428** i want to show in proper format H:mm:ss DD-MM-YY

Comment: You are using a spoon to cut the apple. Hence the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) you'll see that it expects the query resource as the first parameter, the row number as the second parameter, and (optionally) the field name or offset as the third parameter. You're not using the function in anyway that even resembles its purpose.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment above ("my timestamp showing 1357294428 i want to show in proper format H:mm:ss DD-MM-YY"), you're looking for this:

```
date('H:i:s d-m-y', strtotime($i["time_stamp"]));
```

Although if `$i["time_stamp"]` is already a timestamp then you just need this:

```
date('H:i:s d-m-y', $i["time_stamp"]);
```